# Kibana service won't start

Tags: manjaro, elasticsearch, kibana

I am using Manjaro and installed elasticsearch and kibana with

```
yay -S elasticsearch kibana
```

Starting the elasticsearch service works well

```
sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
```

I've configured kibana with the basic settings in /etc/kibana/kibana.yml:

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: "localhost"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
```

But running kibana always fails:

```
❯❯❯ systemctl status kibana                                                                                                                                                              ✘ 7 
● kibana.service - Kibana - dashboard for Elasticsearch
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kibana.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-11-13 12:10:13 CET; 5min ago
    Process: 1609 ExecStart=/usr/bin/node --max-old-space-size=512 /usr/share/kibana/src/cli --config=/etc/kibana/kibana.yml (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1609 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 13 12:10:13 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 13 12:10:13 Trinity systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana - dashboard for Elasticsearch.
Nov 13 12:10:13 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 13 12:10:13 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 13 12:10:13 Trinity systemd[1]: Failed to start Kibana - dashboard for Elasticsearch.
```

Maybe I am overseeing somethink. What should I do to start it properly?

```
journal -u kibana

Nov 13 12:10:10 Trinity systemd[1]: Started Kibana - dashboard for Elasticsearch.
Nov 13 12:10:10 Trinity node[1419]: Kibana does not support the current Node.js version v15.0.1. Please use Node.js v10.22.1.
Nov 13 12:10:10 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 13 12:10:10 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 13 12:10:11 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Nov 13 12:10:11 Trinity systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana - dashboard for Elasticsearch.
Nov 13 12:10:11 Trinity systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana - dashboard for Elasticsearch.
Nov 13 12:10:11 Trinity systemd[1]: Started Kibana - dashboard for Elasticsearch.
Nov 13 12:10:11 Trinity node[1579]: Kibana does not support the current Node.js version v15.0.1. Please use Node.js v10.22.1.
Nov 13 12:10:11 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 13 12:10:11 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 13 12:10:11 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
Nov 13 12:10:11 Trinity systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana - dashboard for Elasticsearch.
Nov 13 12:10:11 Trinity systemd[1]: Started Kibana - dashboard for Elasticsearch.
Nov 13 12:10:11 Trinity node[1589]: Kibana does not support the current Node.js version v15.0.1. Please use Node.js v10.22.1.
Nov 13 12:10:11 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 13 12:10:11 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 13 12:10:12 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Nov 13 12:10:12 Trinity systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana - dashboard for Elasticsearch.
Nov 13 12:10:12 Trinity systemd[1]: Started Kibana - dashboard for Elasticsearch.
Nov 13 12:10:12 Trinity node[1599]: Kibana does not support the current Node.js version v15.0.1. Please use Node.js v10.22.1.
Nov 13 12:10:12 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 13 12:10:12 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 13 12:10:12 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Nov 13 12:10:12 Trinity systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana - dashboard for Elasticsearch.
Nov 13 12:10:12 Trinity systemd[1]: Started Kibana - dashboard for Elasticsearch.
Nov 13 12:10:12 Trinity node[1609]: Kibana does not support the current Node.js version v15.0.1. Please use Node.js v10.22.1.
Nov 13 12:10:12 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 13 12:10:12 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 13 12:10:13 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 13 12:10:13 Trinity systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana - dashboard for Elasticsearch.
Nov 13 12:10:13 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 13 12:10:13 Trinity systemd[1]: kibana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 13 12:10:13 Trinity systemd[1]: Failed to start Kibana - dashboard for Elasticsearch.
```

Comment: Check the logs for errors, edit your question and include them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent countless hours trying to get Kibana to work on Arch and Manjaro. I finally succeeded.

Below are my notes to myself, in case someone else has the same problem.

Be aware that I am a newbie, and frankly, I don't know what I am doing, so proceed with caution.

1. Install Kibana after installing `elasticsearch`

In Arch, is used this command:

```
$sudo pacman -S kibana
```

In Manjaro, I used the Add/Remove Software GUI. Searched for kibana, clicked Install, and Apply

2. After installation of Kibana, I changed these settings in `/etc/kibana/kibana.yml` (uncomment the lines below):

```
$ sudo nano /etc/kibana/kibana.yml

#server.port: 5601
#server.host: "localhost"
#elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]
```

3. Kibana requires `node`, but Kibana 7.9.2-1 does not work with the latest `node` version. So you need an older version of Node to work, specifically Node 10.22.1. To install this older version of Node, I used NVM (Node Version Manager).

I ran these commands:

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.37.0/install.sh | bash
$ export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
$ [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
```

4. Using NVM, install Node 10.22.1.

```
$ nvm install v10.22.1
```

This will install the binary file called "node" in this location: `/home/manjaro1/.nvm/versions/node/v10.22.1/bin`
(be aware that the .nvm directory is hidden)

5. After installation, I renamed my existing node file (`/usr/bin/node`) to (`/usr/bin/node`) I used these commands to achieve that:

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ sudo mv -- node node_backup
```

> Caution: I do not know if renaming this file is a good idea, in regards to other programs.

6. I then copied my new node file to the `/usr/bin`, with this command (making sure I ran the command from the `/usr/bin` directory):

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ sudo cp -- /home/manjaro1/.nvm/version/node/v10.22.1/bin/node node
```

7. I enabled Kibana to run on startup:

```
$ systemctl enable kibana
```

8. I then started Kibana

```
$ systemctl start kibana
```

9. And checked the status:

```
$ systemctl status kibana
```

10. Everything looked good. I then made sure Elasticsearch was running (`systemctl status elasticsearch`) and opened a browser, and went to
    `localhost:5601`

After a few seconds, the Kibana control panel appeared.

---

Useful Notes

1. In step 5 and 6 above, you can possibly leave the existing node file in `/usr/bin`, and copy the version 10.22.1 node file to `/usr/bin` with a new name, for example `node10221`.  In that case, you need to make a change in this file: `/usr/lib/systemd/system/kibana.service` with:

```
$ sudo nano /usr/lib/systemd/system/kibana.service
```

In the line that starts with `ExecStart=/usr/bin/node` change the file name to the new node name, like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node10221
```

Save the file and start or restart Kibana:

```
$ systemctl start kibana
```

or

```
$ systemctl restart kibana
```

2. Make sure you are using `eleasticsearch` 7.9.2-1 and `Kibana` 7.9.2-1 and install `elasticsearch` before `Kibana`
3. If something is wrong when you run:

```
$ systemctl status kibana
```

you can trouble shoot using:

```
$ journalctl -fu kibana.service
```

4. If Kibana fails to start because of permission issues, check permissions with this command:

```
$ ls -l
```

5. My installation is only running locally, so using `localhost` in kibana.yml works fine for me. It is my understanding you need to change this, if you want to allow remote access.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Worked very well. Thank you 